# How to implement custom filters in Polymer 1.7.x

Tags: polymer

I am trying to implement a custom filter using Polymer v1.7.0 currently. However, it does not work at all; when I try to use a filter the output is just the raw expression, unprocessed.

I have tried it like it's done here: https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polymer-patterns/blob/master/snippets/filters/using-custom-filters.html but using this code:

`<div id="toFixed">{{10.123456789 | toFixed(2)}}</div>`

only results in

`{{10.123456789 | toFixed(2)}}` in the resulting document.

Is my linked source outdated? I couldn't find any valuable information in the Polymer docs so a nudge into the right the direction is appreciated.

Comment: These are Polymer 0.5 link. i doubt they work with 1.x versions. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: To filter a value? I mean to 'pipe' an expression through some function to have it printed/formatted differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `pipe` in Polymer 1.x to achieve this. You can directly call an function and pass it the value that you want to

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    {{format(myVal)}}
    <br>{{format("hello")}}
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: "my-element",
    properties: {
      myVal: {
        type: String,
        value: "Hi"
      }
    },
    format: function(input) {
      return input + " John";
    }
  });
</script>

<my-element></my-element>
```